# DotNet core data annotation localization returns resource key instead of resource value

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages, blazor

I need to localize a data annotation error message in the DotNet core. I have created a SharedResource class, but the validation summary returns the resource's key instead of the resource's value.

```
services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
           .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
           {
               options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                   factory.Create(typeof(SharedResources));
           });
```

Comment: This question should be in the Razor Pages section, not in the Blazor section.

Comment: please help me everything working only data annotatins

Answer (score 0):

In resources folder, you need to have SharedResources resource files such as `SharedResource.en-US.resx` and `SharedResource.fi-FI.resx`.

You may also need to set `ResourcesPath` by calling

```
services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
```

and

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(
        LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
        opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
```

Also make sure that the current culture of the user has resource file with appropriate key value pairs.

[Further reference](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/)

Comment: thanks for your replay, i did all this changes everting is working only data annotations is not working